# modifying webkitdragdrop.js use classes instead of ID

Tags: javascript, ipad, drag-and-drop

I've found a script that seems perfect for my needs, but it uses IDs, rather than classes to create ipad-friendly drag & drop elements.

I really need it to use classes, as the draggable elements could potentially be in the thousands.

[edit] I'm not that great at javascript and am having difficulties in understanding how I could alter the script to use classes instead of IDs.

I have also contacted the script author, but have had no reply from him.

I'm offering this bounty as I've not had any response to my original query.

Please could someone change the script below so that it uses classes? [/edit]

Below is the script in its entirety, and [here is the script page](http://www.gotproject.com/blog/post2.html) (API was not helpful to me in being able to use classes vs id).

```
// webkitdragdrop.js v1.0, Mon May 15 2010
//
// Copyright (c) 2010 Tommaso Buvoli (http://www.tommasobuvoli.com)
// No Extra Libraries are required, simply download this file, add it to your pages!
//
// To See this library in action, grab an ipad and head over to http://www.gotproject.com
// webkitdragdrop is freely distributable under the terms of an MIT-style license.


//Description
// Because this library was designed to run without requiring any other libraries, several basic helper functions were implemented
// 6 helper functons in this webkit_tools class have been taked directly from Prototype 1.6.1 (http://prototypejs.org/) (c) 2005-2009 Sam Stephenson

var webkit_tools = 
{
    //$ function - simply a more robust getElementById

    $:function(e)
    {
        if(typeof(e) == 'string')
        {
            return document.getElementById(e);
        }
        return e;
    },

    //extend function - copies the values of b into a (Shallow copy)

    extend:function(a,b)
    {
        for (var key in b)
        {
            a[key] = b[key];    
        }   
        return a;
    },

    //empty function - used as defaut for events

    empty:function()
    {

    },

    //remove null values from an array

    compact:function(a)
    {
        var b = []
        var l = a.length;
        for(var i = 0; i < l; i ++)
        {
            if(a[i] !== null)
            {
                b.push(a[i]);
            }
        }
        return b;
    },

    //DESCRIPTION
    //  This function was taken from the internet (http://robertnyman.com/2006/04/24/get-the-rendered-style-of-an-element/) and returns 
    //  the computed style of an element independantly from the browser
    //INPUT
    //  oELM (DOM ELEMENT) element whose style should be extracted
    //  strCssRule element

    getCalculatedStyle:function(oElm, strCssRule)
    {
        var strValue = "";
        if(document.defaultView && document.defaultView.getComputedStyle){
            strValue = document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(oElm, "").getPropertyValue(strCssRule);
        }
        else if(oElm.currentStyle){
            strCssRule = strCssRule.replace(/\-(\w)/g, function (strMatch, p1){
                return p1.toUpperCase();
            });
            strValue = oElm.currentStyle[strCssRule];
        }
        return strValue;
    },

    //bindAsEventListener function - used to bind events

    bindAsEventListener:function(f,object) 
    {
        var __method = f;
        return function(event) {
            __method.call(object, event || window.event);
        };
    },

    //cumulative offset - courtesy of Prototype (http://www.prototypejs.org)

    cumulativeOffset:function(element) 
    {
        var valueT = 0, valueL = 0;
        do {
          valueT += element.offsetTop  || 0;
          valueL += element.offsetLeft || 0;
          if (element.offsetParent == document.body)
            if (element.style.position == 'absolute') break;

          element = element.offsetParent;
        } while (element);

        return {left : valueL, top : valueT};
    },

    //getDimensions - courtesy of Prototype (http://www.prototypejs.org)

    getDimensions: function(element) 
    {
        var display = element.style.display;
        if (display != 'none' && display != null) // Safari bug
          return {width: element.offsetWidth, height: element.offsetHeight};

        var els = element.style;
        var originalVisibility = els.visibility;
        var originalPosition = els.position;
        var originalDisplay = els.display;
        els.visibility = 'hidden';
        if (originalPosition != 'fixed') // Switching fixed to absolute causes issues in Safari
          els.position = 'absolute';
        els.display = 'block';
        var originalWidth = element.clientWidth;
        var originalHeight = element.clientHeight;
        els.display = originalDisplay;
        els.position = originalPosition;
        els.visibility = originalVisibility;
        return {width: originalWidth, height: originalHeight};
    },

    //hasClassName - courtesy of Prototype (http://www.prototypejs.org)

    hasClassName: function(element, className) 
    {
        var elementClassName = element.className;
        return (elementClassName.length > 0 && (elementClassName == className ||
        new RegExp("(^|\\s)" + className + "(\\s|$)").test(elementClassName)));
    },

    //addClassName - courtesy of Prototype (http://www.prototypejs.org)

    addClassName: function(element, className) 
    {
        if (!this.hasClassName(element, className))
            element.className += (element.className ? ' ' : '') + className;
        return element;
    },

    //removeClassName - courtesy of Prototype (http://www.prototypejs.org)

    removeClassName: function(element, className) 
    {
        element.className = this.strip(element.className.replace(new RegExp("(^|\\s+)" + className + "(\\s+|$)"), ' '));
        return element;
    },

    //strip - courtesy of Prototype (http://www.prototypejs.org)

    strip:function(s)
    {
        return s.replace(/^\s+/, '').replace(/\s+$/, '');
    }

}

//Description
// Droppable fire events when a draggable is dropped on them

var webkit_droppables = function()
{
    this.initialize = function()
    {
        this.droppables = [];
        this.droppableRegions = [];
    }

    this.add = function(root, instance_props)
    {
        root = webkit_tools.$(root);
        var default_props = {accept : [], hoverClass : null, onDrop : webkit_tools.empty, onOver : webkit_tools.empty, onOut : webkit_tools.empty};
        default_props = webkit_tools.extend(default_props, instance_props || {});
        this.droppables.push({r : root, p : default_props});        
    }

    this.remove = function(root)
    {
        root = webkit_tools.$(root);
        var d = this.droppables;
        var i = d.length;
        while(i--)
        {
            if(d[i].r == root)
            {
                d[i] = null;
                this.droppables = webkit_tools.compact(d);
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    //calculate position and size of all droppables

    this.prepare = function()
    {
        var d = this.droppables;
        var i = d.length;
        var dR = [];
        var r = null;

        while(i--)
        {
            r = d[i].r;         
            if(r.style.display != 'none')
            {
                dR.push({i : i, size : webkit_tools.getDimensions(r), offset : webkit_tools.cumulativeOffset(r)})           
            }
        }

        this.droppableRegions = dR;
    }

    this.finalize = function(x,y,r,e)
    {
        var indices = this.isOver(x,y);
        var index = this.maxZIndex(indices);
        var over = this.process(index,r);
        if(over)
        {
            this.drop(index, r,e);
        }
        this.process(-1,r);
        return over;    
    }

    this.check = function(x,y,r)
    {
        var indices = this.isOver(x,y);
        var index = this.maxZIndex(indices);
        return this.process(index,r);       
    }

    this.isOver = function(x, y)
    {
        var dR = this.droppableRegions;
        var i = dR.length;
        var active = [];
        var r = 0;
        var maxX = 0;
        var minX = 0;
        var maxY = 0;
        var minY = 0;

        while(i--)
        {
            r = dR[i];

            minY = r.offset.top;
            maxY = minY + r.size.height;

            if((y > minY) && (y < maxY))
            {
                minX = r.offset.left;
                maxX = minX + r.size.width;

                if((x > minX) && (x < maxX))
                {
                    active.push(r.i);
                }           
            }       
        }

        return active;  
    }

    this.maxZIndex = function(indices)
    {
        var d = this.droppables;
        var l = indices.length;
        var index = -1;

        var maxZ = -100000000;
        var curZ = 0;

        while(l--)
        {
            curZ = parseInt(d[indices[l]].r.style.zIndex || 0);
            if(curZ > maxZ)
            {
                maxZ = curZ;
                index = indices[l];     
            }   
        }

        return index;   
    }

    this.process = function(index, draggableRoot)
    {
        //only perform update if a change has occured
        if(this.lastIndex != index)
        {
            //remove previous
            if(this.lastIndex != null)
            {
                var d = this.droppables[this.lastIndex]
                var p = d.p;
                var r = d.r;

                if(p.hoverClass)
                {
                    webkit_tools.removeClassName(r,p.hoverClass);
                }
                p.onOut();
                this.lastIndex = null;
                this.lastOutput = false;
            }

            //add new
            if(index != -1)
            {
                var d = this.droppables[index]
                var p = d.p;
                var r = d.r;

                if(this.hasClassNames(draggableRoot, p.accept))
                {
                    if(p.hoverClass)
                    {
                        webkit_tools.addClassName(r,p.hoverClass);
                    }
                    p.onOver();             
                    this.lastIndex = index;
                    this.lastOutput = true; 
                }
            }   
        }
        return this.lastOutput;
    }

    this.drop = function(index, r, e)
    {
        if(index != -1)
        {
            this.droppables[index].p.onDrop(r,e);
        }
    }

    this.hasClassNames = function(r, names)
    {
        var l = names.length;
        if(l == 0){return true}
        while(l--)
        {
            if(webkit_tools.hasClassName(r,names[l]))
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    this.initialize();
}

webkit_drop = new webkit_droppables();

//Description
//webkit draggable - allows users to drag elements with their hands

var webkit_draggable = function(r, ip)
{
    this.initialize = function(root, instance_props)
    {
        this.root = webkit_tools.$(root);
        var default_props = {scroll : false, revert : false, handle : this.root, zIndex : 1000, onStart : webkit_tools.empty, onEnd : webkit_tools.empty};      

        this.p = webkit_tools.extend(default_props, instance_props || {});
        default_props.handle = webkit_tools.$(default_props.handle);
        this.prepare();
        this.bindEvents();
    }

    this.prepare = function()
    {
        var rs = this.root.style;

        //set position
        if(webkit_tools.getCalculatedStyle(this.root,'position') != 'absolute')
        {
            rs.position = 'relative';
        }

        //set top, right, bottom, left
        rs.top = rs.top || '0px';
        rs.left = rs.left || '0px';
        rs.right = "";
        rs.bottom = "";     

        //set zindex;
        rs.zIndex = rs.zIndex || '0';
    }

    this.bindEvents = function()
    {
        var handle = this.p.handle;

        this.ts = webkit_tools.bindAsEventListener(this.touchStart, this);
        this.tm = webkit_tools.bindAsEventListener(this.touchMove, this);
        this.te = webkit_tools.bindAsEventListener(this.touchEnd, this);        

        handle.addEventListener("touchstart", this.ts, false);
        handle.addEventListener("touchmove", this.tm, false);
        handle.addEventListener("touchend", this.te, false);
    }   

    this.destroy = function()
    {
        var handle = this.p.handle;

        handle.removeEventListener("touchstart", this.ts);
        handle.removeEventListener("touchmove", this.tm);
        handle.removeEventListener("touchend", this.te);    
    }

    this.set = function(key, value)
    {
        this.p[key] = value;
    }

    this.touchStart = function(event)
    {
        //prepare needed variables
        var p = this.p;
        var r = this.root;
        var rs = r.style;
        var t = event.targetTouches[0];     

        //get position of touch
        touchX = t.pageX;
        touchY = t.pageY;

        //set base values for position of root
        rs.top = this.root.style.top || '0px';
        rs.left = this.root.style.left || '0px';
        rs.bottom = null;
        rs.right = null;

        var rootP = webkit_tools.cumulativeOffset(r);
        var cp = this.getPosition();

        //save event properties
        p.rx = cp.x;
        p.ry = cp.y;        
        p.tx = touchX;
        p.ty = touchY;
        p.z = parseInt(this.root.style.zIndex);

        //boost zIndex
        rs.zIndex = p.zIndex;
        webkit_drop.prepare();
        p.onStart();
    }

    this.touchMove = function(event)
    {
        event.preventDefault();
        event.stopPropagation();

        //prepare needed variables
        var p = this.p;
        var r = this.root;
        var rs = r.style;
        var t = event.targetTouches[0];
        if(t == null){return}

        var curX = t.pageX;
        var curY = t.pageY;

        var delX = curX - p.tx;
        var delY = curY - p.ty;

        rs.left = p.rx + delX + 'px';
        rs.top  = p.ry + delY + 'px';

        //scroll window
        if(p.scroll)
        {
            s = this.getScroll(curX, curY);
            if((s[0] != 0) || (s[1] != 0))
            {
                window.scrollTo(window.scrollX + s[0], window.scrollY + s[1]);
            }
        }

        //check droppables
        webkit_drop.check(curX, curY, r);

        //save position for touchEnd
        this.lastCurX = curX;
        this.lastCurY = curY;
    }

    this.touchEnd = function(event)
    {
        var r = this.root;
        var p = this.p;
        var dropped = webkit_drop.finalize(this.lastCurX, this.lastCurY, r, event);

        if(((p.revert) && (!dropped)) || (p.revert === 'always'))
        {
            //revert root
            var rs = r.style;
            rs.top = (p.ry + 'px');
            rs.left = (p.rx + 'px');
        }

        r.style.zIndex = this.p.z;
        this.p.onEnd();
    }

    this.getPosition = function()
    {
        var rs = this.root.style;
        return {x : parseInt(rs.left || 0), y : parseInt(rs.top  || 0)}
    }

    this.getScroll = function(pX, pY)
    {
        //read window variables
        var sX = window.scrollX;
        var sY = window.scrollY;

        var wX = window.innerWidth;
        var wY = window.innerHeight;

        //set contants      
        var scroll_amount = 10; //how many pixels to scroll
        var scroll_sensitivity = 100; //how many pixels from border to start scrolling from.

        var delX = 0;
        var delY = 0;       

        //process vertical y scroll
        if(pY - sY < scroll_sensitivity)
        {
            delY = -scroll_amount;
        }
        else
        if((sY + wY) - pY < scroll_sensitivity)
        {
            delY = scroll_amount;
        }

        //process horizontal x scroll
        if(pX - sX < scroll_sensitivity)
        {
            delX = -scroll_amount;
        }
        else
        if((sX + wX) - pX < scroll_sensitivity)
        {
            delX = scroll_amount;
        }

        return [delX, delY]
    }

    //contructor
    this.initialize(r, ip);
}

//Description
//webkit_click class. manages click events for draggables

var webkit_click = function(r, ip)
{
    this.initialize = function(root, instance_props)
    {
        var default_props = {onClick : webkit_tools.empty};

        this.root = webkit_tools.$(root);
        this.p = webkit_tools.extend(default_props, instance_props || {});
        this.bindEvents();
    }

    this.bindEvents = function()
    {
        var root = this.root;

        //bind events to local scope
        this.ts = webkit_tools.bindAsEventListener(this.touchStart,this);
        this.tm = webkit_tools.bindAsEventListener(this.touchMove,this);
        this.te = webkit_tools.bindAsEventListener(this.touchEnd,this);

        //add Listeners
        root.addEventListener("touchstart", this.ts, false);
        root.addEventListener("touchmove", this.tm, false);
        root.addEventListener("touchend", this.te, false);

        this.bound = true;  
    }   

    this.touchStart = function()
    {
        this.moved = false;
        if(this.bound == false)
        {
            this.root.addEventListener("touchmove", this.tm, false);
            this.bound = true;
        }
    }

    this.touchMove = function()
    {
        this.moved = true;
        this.root.removeEventListener("touchmove", this.tm);
        this.bound = false;
    }

    this.touchEnd = function()
    {
        if(this.moved == false)
        {
            this.p.onClick();
        }
    }

    this.setEvent = function(f)
    {
        if(typeof(f) == 'function')
        {
            this.p.onClick = f;
        }
    }

    this.unbind = function()
    {
        var root = this.root;
        root.removeEventListener("touchstart", this.ts);
        root.removeEventListener("touchmove", this.tm);
        root.removeEventListener("touchend", this.te);
    }

    //call constructor
    this.initialize(r, ip);
}
```

Comment: This seems like a large project to modify the script to use classes instead of ids.  Is it possible for you to modify your code to use ids in some scripted manner (ex: find everything of a given class, generate an id for each, and loop through all of them?)

Comment: Thanks for your comment Michael. Yes, I could do this, but had thought that given the potential IDs would number thousands it seemed more elegant to use classes. Also, (I know this is bad, but a "more experienced" developer has been working on this project with me and) has already used IDs to identify DB records. Unfortunately, the IDs are basic numbers such as 85, 104, 9.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your classnames are unique, the solution is rather simple. You can change the `$` function to get by class name instead of by id:

```
var webkit_tools = 
{
    //$ function - simply a more robust getElementById

    $:function(e)
    {
        if(typeof(e) == 'string')
        {
            return document.getElementsByClassName(e)[0];
            // return document.getElementById(e);
        }
        return e;
    },
    ... snipped ...
```

I've verified the above solution works (dragging and dropping) on my iPhone, but again, if the classnames are not unique, some added work will be in order based on the script's current implementation.

~~~EDIT~~~

In re-reading your request, you state that there will in fact NOT be unique classnames, hence the need for some sort of "bulk" drag/drop functionality. I've modified/extended the framework to support this. You can find the source for the modified version here:

https://gist.github.com/2474416

I had to change the API slightly. The dropabble API is unchanged, so passing a classname will simply add/remove the whole list of elements matching the classname passed. The clickable/draggable API was not so easy. To avoid a harsh rewrite, I updated the initialize methods for draggable/clickable to take an element ref rather than id or classname.

Correspondingly, I added a `bulk_draggable(clazzname, options)` and `bulk_clickable(clazzname, options)` function that basically iterates over the matched elements and calls the corresponding initializers. These functions return an array of draggables/clickables (one for each matched element).

Let me know if the "new" API is unclear. I did this rather quickly and lightly tested the happy paths, but can't invest and substantial amount of time rewriting the entire script.

Comment: Hi cozykozy, thanks so much for your assistance. Unfortunately, I've had no chance over the past week to test this out and now I have 1 min to accept an answer! Therefore, I've accepted your answer and will try it out today. I'll upvote when I've had a decent attempt with your altered script.

Comment: Cozykozy, your changes have been really helpful and I've got it working with classes. The only problem is that I can't drop items into the droppable boxes. The droppable boxes do not seem to recognise `.draggable` items and the hover state change (`.hd`) does not occur. Any ideas? Also, I tried to add a bulk_droppable based on your bulk_draggable and it doesn't seem to be working but this may because the draggable items are not being recognised.

Comment: Circey, I don't seem to be having the same problem with the droppable areas. If you can share a fiddler example of something that isn't working, I might be able to help you out. Adding a bulk_droppable wouldn't be too bad (it'd essentially be a pass through to the .add function).

Comment: hi again, I've got a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rGz3A/7/ - I've used `<li>`, but even if I change these to divs, it doesn't add the hover class and doesn't add the items to the box.

Comment: Circey, The "version" of the webkit drag/drop file is not the same as the one I posted a link to (see my gist above). I've made a new jsfiddle showing you how to use library with my changes: http://jsfiddle.net/TqfRm/8/ . Essentially, to get the drop targets to hook up, you need to pass the name of the class to webkit_drop.add(); your example was still using the ID, which will not work based on the changes I had to make. If you only want to make, say, 1 div droppable, you could just put a really specific class on that one div. Let me know if you're still unsure of the API.

Comment: Hi cozykozy, I know this is 6 weeks after you left your last comment and I apologise. This is a personal project and all paying jobs/work takes priority over this. In any case, yes everything is dragging and dropping fine, with just one problem - the li.draggable are not displaying in the .drop div once dropped. I expected the li.draggables to list within the .drop div; what am I missing?